# Rails, generate MD5 hash of the record's ID and save that also

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, model, callback, md5

After saving a rails model, I'd like to generate an md5 hash of the ID and save it in the database with the object.

My question is, how do I define the method that does this? I need the ID to do the calculation, but this isn't done until after the save?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an after_create callback in the model to do this.

```
class YourClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :hash_it

  private

  def hash_it
    self.md5_hashed = id.md5_your_hash_method
  end

end
```

fyi the 4 'after' callbacks available are:

```
after_validation  
after_create
after_save
after_commit
```

Comment: you should detail further to avoid recursion issues

Comment: now I am wondering - how will this get saved to the database?  Does rails do another save for me? Or should this really be after_create? Or is the ID available at the point?

Comment: maybe this should be after_create ? yes that is sounding better

Comment: Original posters "after save" had led me there, but this is the ID we're talking about so I certainly do not expect it to change after original initial creation/population.

Comment: You need to save the record after setting this or use `update_attribute`.